# AVR TWI (I2C) problem: Operand 1 out of range

Tags: avr, i2c, atmega, atmelstudio

I´m using Atmega2560 and 24c16A EEPROM for testing an I2C code. For every state transition, controller responds by changing the status register TWSR. After start condition is transmitted, EEPROM responds and then also for Device address and write instruction (SLA+R/W), status register updates fine. But when I transmit next 8 bits, instead of ACK (Data byte sent ACK), status changes to repeated start. The code is given below. I never could find the possible solution to make it work.

```
.include "./m2560def.inc"
.list
.cseg
.org 0x00
jmp inicio      ; PC = 0x0000   RESET

inicio:
    LDI R21, HIGH(RAMEND)           ;Set Up Stack
    OUT SPH, R21
    LDI R21, LOW(RAMEND)    
    OUT SPL, R21

    CALL I2C_INIT                   ;Initialize TWI(I2C)
    CALL I2C_START                  ;Transmit START condition
    LDI  R27, 0b11010000            ;SLA(0b1001100) + W(0)
    CALL I2C_WRITE                  ;Write R27 ato the I2C bus
    LDI  R27, 0b11110000            ;Data to be transmitted
    CALL I2C_WRITE                  ;Write R27 ato the I2C bus
    CALL I2C_STOP                   ;Transmit STOP condition

HERE: RJMP HERE

;----------------------------I2C_INIT-----------------------------
I2C_INIT:
     LDI    R21, 0              
     OUT    TWSR, R21           ;Set prescaler bits to 0
     LDI    R21, 0x47           ;R21 = 0x47
     OUT    TWBR, R21           ;Fclk = 50 KHz (8 MHz Xtal)
     LDI    R21, (1<<TWEN)      ;R21 = 0x04
     OUT    TWCR, R21           ;HEnable TWI (I2C)
     RET

;----------------------------I2C_START-----------------------------
I2C_START: 
     LDI    R21, (1<<TWINT)|1<<(TWSTA)|(1<<TWEN)
     OUT    TWCR, R21           ;Transmit START condition
 WAIT1:  
     IN     R21, TWCR           ;Read Control Register TWCR into R21
     SBRS   R21, TWINT          ;Skip the next line if TWINT is 1
     RJMP   WAIT1               ;Jump a WAIT1 if TWINT is 1
     RET  

 ;----------------------------I2C_WRITE -----------------------------
 I2C_WRITE:
     OUT    TWDR, R27           ;Move the byte into TWRD
     LDI    R21,  (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN)
     OUT    TWCR, R21           ;Configure TWCR to send TWDR
  WAIT3:
     IN     R21, TWCR           ;Read Control Register TWCR into R21
     SBRS   R21, TWINT          ;Skip the next line if TWINT is 1
     RJMP   WAIT3               ;Jump a WAIT3 if TWINT is 1
     RET

 ;----------------------------I2C_STOP------------------------------
 I2C_STOP:
     LDI    R21, (1<<TWINT)|1<<(TWSTO)|(1<<TWEN)
     OUT    TWCR, R21           ;Transmit STOP condition
     RET

;----------------------------I2C_READ------------------------------
I2C_READ:
     LDI    R21,  (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN)
     OUT    TWCR, R21   
WAIT2:
    IN      R21, TWCR           ;Read Control Register TWCR into R21
    SBRS    R21, TWINT          ;Skip the next line if TWINT is 1
    RJMP    WAIT2               ;Jump a WAIT2 if TWINT is 1
    IN      R27, TWCR           ;Read received data into R21
    RET
```

The output is

```
D:\ATMEL_AVR\I2C_TWI\I2C_TWI.asm(41,0): error: Operand 1 out of range: 0xb9
D:\ATMEL_AVR\I2C_TWI\I2C_TWI.asm(43,0): error: Operand 1 out of range: 0xb8
D:\ATMEL_AVR\I2C_TWI\I2C_TWI.asm(45,0): error: Operand 1 out of range: 0xbc
D:\ATMEL_AVR\I2C_TWI\I2C_TWI.asm(51,0): error: Operand 1 out of range: 0xbc
D:\ATMEL_AVR\I2C_TWI\I2C_TWI.asm(53,0): error: Operand 2 out of range: 0xbc
D:\ATMEL_AVR\I2C_TWI\I2C_TWI.asm(60,0): error: Operand 1 out of range: 0xbb
D:\ATMEL_AVR\I2C_TWI\I2C_TWI.asm(62,0): error: Operand 1 out of range: 0xbc
D:\ATMEL_AVR\I2C_TWI\I2C_TWI.asm(64,0): error: Operand 2 out of range: 0xbc
D:\ATMEL_AVR\I2C_TWI\I2C_TWI.asm(72,0): error: Operand 1 out of range: 0xbc
D:\ATMEL_AVR\I2C_TWI\I2C_TWI.asm(78,0): error: Operand 1 out of range: 0xbc
D:\ATMEL_AVR\I2C_TWI\I2C_TWI.asm(80,0): error: Operand 2 out of range: 0xbc
D:\ATMEL_AVR\I2C_TWI\I2C_TWI.asm(83,0): error: Operand 2 out of range: 0xbc
    Assembly failed, 12 errors, 0 warnings
```

The code lines involved in these errors are:

```
     OUT    TWSR, R21
     OUT    TWBR, R21
     OUT    TWCR, R21
     OUT    TWCR, R21
     IN     R21, TWCR   
     OUT    TWDR, R27
     OUT    TWCR, R21
     IN     R21, TWCR
     OUT    TWCR, R21
     OUT    TWCR, R21
     IN     R21, TWCR
     IN     R27, TWCR
```

Comment: Why are you using assembler for that 'huge' AVR? Use C, or any other higher level language, and the compiler will take care of how to access which register for you.

Answer (score 1):

In AVR normally all I/O registers are mapped into the memory space, starting from address `0x0020`

`in` and `out` instructions could be used ONLY with the first 64 of them (with 0x20...0x5F memory addresses)
 `sbi`, `cbi`, `sbis` and `sbic` has further limitation and can be used only with first 32 I/O registres (with memory address 0x20...0x3F). Please refer to the [AVR Instruction Set Manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf)

In the [datasheet to ATmega2560](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-2549-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf), section 33 "Register Summary", page 401, you can see the TWI registers have addresses 0xB8 thru 0xBD, i.e. they cannot be accessed using `in` and `out` instructions. You have to use `STS` and `LDS`. 
I.e. `LDS R21, TWCR` instead of  `IN R21, TWCR` etc.

Also, always be careful when accessing the first 64 registers. Make sure the corresponding names are defining their I/O and not RAM addresses. I.e. PORTA should be equal to 0x02 (IO address for `in` / `out` instruction) and not 0x22 (RAM address or PORTA, which, when accessed using `in` or `out`, equals to EEARH register).